# Any difference between renderToPipeableStream vs renderToNodeStream if no suspense was used

Tags: reactjs, streaming

I understand that we use Suspense to mark the boundary. If there is no suspense, that means the render will be done in just a single pass, which is the same as the SSR without streaming.

Are we getting any benefit from using renderToPieableStream - the new stream, if there is no Suspense usage in the codebase at all?

Also, would that mean renderToNodeStream would be doing the same thing?

Answer (score 2):

There's no benefit to using `renderToPipeableStream()` in React 18 if you are not using the `Suspense` component.

However, there is a major benefit to using `renderToPipeableStream()` instead of `renderToNodeStream()` because the latter is actually being depreciated - it also didn't work very well since it could not wait for data.

`renderToNodeStream()` was basically one step closer to full SSR than `renderToString()` but still not quite there.

This React 18 Github announcement highlights everything really well.

https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/22

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

`Suspense` tells react that there is an async component is getting prepared so when the async component finished data fetching, react will inject that part into the correct HTML spot.

Imagine an Amazon product page, we first see the product images and details about the product and then we see the comments, reviews, footer etc. down below. with `renderToPipeableStream()` we can first send the top part, images, and details about the product and then rest of page can be loaded. this way you can interact with the part that is loaded while the rest is loading. Because after this part is loaded, react injects its script. this stream is writable stream

```
export function renderToPipeableStream(children: ReactNode, options?: RenderToPipeableStreamOptions): PipeableStream;

export interface PipeableStream {
    abort(): void;
    pipe<Writable extends NodeJS.WritableStream>(destination: Writable): Writable}
```

with `renderToNodeStream`, you start to send the first bit of HTML to the client, client will see the content but will not be able to interact with it till the streaming is fully done and then the client hydrates it, injects the script. If you were using `renderToNodeStream`, you had to go over all the pages to see if they had a data fetching function, you had to finish data fetching for all the pages and then you were going to start streaming. this stream is a readable stream

```
export function renderToNodeStream(element: ReactElement): NodeJS.ReadableStream;
```